# How to change the value of a column items using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my fist question on stackoverflow.

I'm implementing a Machine Learning classification algorithm and I want to generalize it for any input dataset that have their target class in the last column. For that, I want to modify all values of this column without needing to know the names of each column or rows using pandas in python.

For example, let's suppose I load a dataset:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('random_dataset.csv')
```

Let's say the last column has the following data:

```
0   dog
1   dog
2   cat
3   dog
4   cat
```

I want to change each "dog" appearence to 1 and each cat appearance to 0, so that the column would look:

```
0   1
1   1
2   0
3   1
4   0
```

I have found some ways of changing the values of specific cells using pandas, but for this case, what would be the best way to do that?

I appreciate each answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pandas.Categorical](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html):

```py
df['column'] = pd.Categorical(df['column']).codes
```

You can also use the built in functionality for this too:

```py
df['column'] = df['column'].astype('category').cat.codes
```

Comment: This is simple and easy! The thing is that the results are not binary, but with a bit of extra code we can work around it.

Answer (score 1):

use the [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and map the values as per requirement:

```
df['col_name'] = df['col_name'].map({'dog' : 1 , 'cat': 0})
```

OR -> Use [factorize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html)(Encode the object as an enumerated type) -> if you wanna assign random numeric values

```
df['col_name'] = df['col_name'].factorize()[0]
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
0    1
1    1
2    0
3    1
4    0
```

Comment: Thanks! To achieve what I wanted to (to get to that result without knowing the column name) I had to add some extra code, but using map was a nice tip.